# How to get the real time download speed on Android?

Tags: android

I have searched many sites . All of them told me to download something to get the download speed .

But I need known the real time speed when my phone is downloading something.Not my code to download it.

And also , download other things can only mean the speed of those sites . It dose not apply to other sites or other file's download speed.

**So , my questiong is**: If I'm download something use Android by any way. How can I get the real download speed of this?

I found some app use VPN to get the flow of every app, is there any way Simpler?

Answer (score 0):

If you know when your device is actively downloading something, you could create your own simple app that uses [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html)

When you press a button, you use getTotalRxBytes() to get the total amount of bytes transmitted since device boot. You then use this as a baseline. You can then have a stop button, which, when pressed, will call getTotalRxBytes() again and show the difference in total bytes transferred during that time period. You can then use that to calculate the effective speed. Also note that you can pass a UID of a specific application to the method if you know the specific UID for the application you want to monitor.